# Bypass TextBox's character limit?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

> PROBLEM

I've found that a `TextBox` has a limitation of **32.767** chars, this means a `Short` max value.

> QUESTION

I could bypass that limit by subclassing a `Textbox` control? (instead of using a `RichTextBox`)

Comment: While a TextBox has properties to use it as a multi-lined edit control then it does not seems to have much sense to implicity that char limitation.

Comment: Probably stupid question but why you need to do that ? :)

Comment: To paste inside more than 32.767 characters, simply as that :P, using a TextBox I improve the performance in generally than using a RichTextBox (while I just want to perform copy/paste operations in an edit control).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`TextBoxBase.MaxLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

> If the MaxLength property is set to 0, the maximum number of characters
>   the user can enter is 2147483646 or an amount based on available
>   memory, whichever is smaller.